# Change color placeholder text «Open files an folders» in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> → text `Open files an folders` has gray dim color.

[image: Open flies and folders]

I open `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` → `Theme - Default` → `Default.sublime-theme` and I tried to find the necessary class for this text, but I didn't find.

How I can change color for `Open files an folders`?

Comment: What are you trying to change - the font color? Font size? Background color?

Comment: @MattDMo, I want to change font color of the text `Open files an folders`.